# What is the difference between the two versions of mongoid first_or_create

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I was going over mongoid documentation https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

and it is not clear to me what is difference between first_or_create & first_or_create!

Can someone help me understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could take a look at

https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html

**create**  = Insert a document or multiple documents into the database

**create!** = Insert a document or multiple documents into the database, raising an error if a validation error occurs.